# Get the value of first property in generic list

Tags: c#

I want to extract the value of the first property in a generic list.
The first property is always a Int32 (not nullable)

Example of list

```
IEnumerable<T> items
```

The value of the first property in every row should create a `LinkedList<int>`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Does the first property have a name?

Comment: If you design everything yourself, you could make it expect an interface instead of allowing <T>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the "first property" on a generic type is something known to the caller of the method that converts your `items` to `LinkedList`, the caller can pass a lambda that selects the first (second, third) item as needed, like this:

```
public static LinkedList<V> ToLinkedList<T,V>(
    this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T,V> selector
) {
    return new LinkedList<V>(items.Select(selector));
}
```

You can call this method like this:

```
LinkedList<int> res = items.ToLinkedList(item => item.FirstField);
```

This approach lets you stay away from modifying your classes by introducing unnecessary interfaces, and allows working with third-party classes as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Where do i find the "FirstField", i dont know the name of the property..

Comment: @anpe Where does the class come from if you don't know the name of the first field?

Comment: Hi again. It is a generic T. So the name of the first property can change. Have tried typeof(T).GetProperties().First() but no luck.

Comment: @anpe Does the caller know the type then? Can the caller pass you a selector, or at least a string with a name to let you use reflection? The order of properties is too fragile to rely upon: although you can certainly do it, it may give you different results on other systems (say, on Mono vs. MS .NET).

Comment: @anpe Did you get a wrong property in `ypeof(T).GetProperties().First()`?

Comment: the caller know the name of property, so i can pass it. But how can i resolve a string name to property?

Comment: @anpe You are welcome! I assume you solved it by filtering the `GetProperties()` result with the name passed by the caller, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try to select the retuned type of the methode of the generic element

```
public static U GetElement<U>(List<U> sourcetype)
{  
 return (from source in sourcetype where source.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetGetMethod().ReturnType == typeof(LinkedList<int>)).FirstOrDefault() != null select source).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

return can be null...

Best Regards.